# django accessing to models takes so much time

Tags: python, mysql, django, templates, render

I have a model like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3072)
    severity = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    reception_timestamp = models.DateField()
    version = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mail_archive_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    component_id = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    technician_at_work = models.BooleanField()
    timestamp = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    system = models.ForeignKey(System)
    event_code = models.ForeignKey(EventCode)
```

and in my views.py file I try to access to a MySql database where the information resides.

I run some QuerySets operations and after that I proceed to extract the information I need from the Model to render it to an html template, but it is taking too much time extracting the information:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(system_id=system_id).filter(timestamp__range=[from_date, now])
return [ e.timestamp, e.system.serial_number, e.version, e.event_code.code, e.description, e.severity, e.reception_timestamp for e in events ]
```

I tried a few things, like create a generator and send it to the template, to consume it rendering the HTML doc, but it is taking the same amount of time accessing to the information.

What can I do? It takes one or two minutes to grab only 270 rows.
I detected that the query takes a few seconds, but is the access to the information that consumes the rest of time. How can I boost this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1) QuerySets are evaluated lazily, so timing them can be a little odd.  Does the "events = Event.objects..." line take a few seconds, or have you timed the queryset *plus* fetching the data?  The latter would look like this:

```
start = time.time()
# build lazy queryset:
events = Event.objects.filter(system_id=system_id).filter(timestamp__range=[from_date, now])
# evaluate and flatten queryset:
res = [ e.timestamp, e.system.serial_number, e.version, e.event_code.code, e.description, e.severity, e.reception_timestamp for e in events ]
logging.info('query took %s', time.time()-start)
```

2) Instead of having a separate for loop, you can get the QuerySet to output the fields directly for you with the [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method. To wit:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(system_id=system_id).filter(timestamp__range=[from_date, now])
event_vals = events.values_list('timestamp', 'system.serial_number') # more here
return event_vals
```

The first line builds a lazy QuerySet describing what kind of data you want.  The 2nd line asks Django to only give you a list of tuples. It reordered and flattens the data for you, and might be faster than explicitly converting all the rows to Models, then extracting the data using a separate loop.

Comment: But the values_list function doesn't fetch foreign keys values, does it?
Like 'system.serial_number' in order to access to the 'system' attribute and then look for the 'serial_number' value.

Comment: I found it! With double underscore (__) instead of a dot (.)
Thank you!